# When a database table is vertically partitioned, what is the relationship between the partitioned table and the table before partitioning?

Tags: database, partition, relational-algebra

While studying database related content, I came across the following:

> When table `R` is vertically partitioned into `R1`, `R2`, `R3`..., `Rn`, it is
> said that it can be expressed as `R` = `R1`⋈`R2`⋈`R3`...⋈`Rn`. (`⋈` is the `join`
> symbol)

However, if the join symbol is used without any special conditions, it becomes a Cartesian product, so doesn't that result in much more tuples than in the original table R? Can you please explain why the existing table is represented as a join of a partitioned table?

Comment: My interpretation is that it’s a **natural join**, not a cross-join. Anyway, don’t spend too much time thinking about it because current RDBMS and SQL implementations are far, far removed from mathematically-pure database theory (for example, I’m not aware of any RDBMS that supports true natural joins (other than hacking it by matching same-name columns, which is (for want of a better phrase) just dumb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That operator means natural join.  See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra:

> Natural join (⋈) is a binary operator that is written as (R ⋈ S) where R and S are relations.[2] The result of the natural join is the set of all combinations of tuples in R and S that are equal on their common attribute names.

Comment: Natural joins in SQL would be great if they used predefined FK constraints for the join criteria instead of attribute/column names. But this is just yet another thing to add to my “Why is SQL’s ergonomics _so bad_?” list of examples.

Comment: @Dai Joins on FKs are frequent, but constraints need not hold, be declared or be known to query. Argument & result table meanings are necessary & sufficient for querying. The join you describe wouldn't be a natural join, but I guess you are sloppily talking about a join shorthand USING a FK or ON a UNIQUE-FK equality.

Comment: @philipxy Right, but I _naturally_ disagree with your assessment of my thoughts as "sloppy" :)

Comment: What do you mean by 'combinations of tuples'?

Answer (score 0):

⋈ is natural join. (When used with 2 relation arguments & no others.) Natural join is Cartesian product when there are no common columns. But in the quote the assumption is that the partitioning is done so that there is a set of key values all tables use. So Cartesian product doesn't come up. Every partition has the same number of rows & the same key content & they differ in additional column content. Each join adds some more additional column data until you get back the original table.